# Let’s close our eyes

Tags: word-request

Let’s close our eyes. There’s black space. There’s a black circle in the center. The circle is not distinguished from the other black surroundings.

What English words do describe this circle which is not distinguished from surroundings?

Comment: It is imaginary.

Comment: How do you _know_ there is a black circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the black circle is not distinguishable from the black surroundings by sight, then it must be invisible.

If it is not distinguishable at all, I would say it is conceptual, or, as Weather Vane says, "imaginary".